# Mule connector config needs dynamic attributes

Tags: spring, mule, mule-component

I have develop a new Connector. This connector requires to be configured with two parameters, lets say:

- default_trip_timeout_milis
- default_trip_threshold

[image]

Challenge is, I want read ${myValue_a} and ${myValue_a} from an API, using an HTTP call, **not** from a file or inline values.

Since this is a connector, I need to make this API call somewhere before connectors are initialized.

FlowVars aren't an option, since they are initialized with the Flows, and this is happening before in the Mule app life Cycle.

My idea is to create an Spring Bean implementing **Initialisable**, so it will be called before Connectors are init, and here, using any java based libs (Spring RestTemplate?) , call API, get values, and store them somewhere (context? objectStore?) , so the connector can access them.

Make sense? Any other ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mmm you could make a class that will create the properties in the startup and in this class obtain the API properties via http request. Example below:

```
 public class PropertyInit implements InitializingBean,FactoryBean {

    private Properties props = new Properties();

    @Override
    public Object getObject() throws Exception {
        return props;
    }

    @Override
    public Class getObjectType() {
        return Properties.class;
    }
 }
```

Now you should be able to load this property class with:

```
  <context:property-placeholder properties-ref="propertyInit"/>
```

Hope you like this idea. I used this approach in a previous project.

Answer (score 1):

I want to give you first a strong warning on doing this. If you go down this path then you risk breaking your application in very strange ways because if any other components depend on this component you are having dynamic components on startup, you will break them, and you should think if there are other ways to achieve this behaviour instead of using properties.

That said the way to do this would be to use a proxy pattern, which is a proxy for the component you recreate whenever its properties are changed. So you will need to create a class which extends `Circuit Breaker`, which encapsulates and instance of `Circuit Breaker` which is recreated whenever its properties change. These properties must not be used outside of the proxy class as other components may read these properties at startup and then not refresh, you must keep this in mind that anything which might directly or indirectly access these properties cannot do so in their initialisation phase or your application will break.

It's worth taking a look at SpringCloudConfig which allows for you to have a properties server and then all your applications can hot-reload those properties at runtime when they change. Not sure if you can take that path in Mule if SpringCloud is supported yet but it's a nice thing to know exists.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will investigate all possible ways!